# How to read Xml to Linq from service

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a string data get from service [Location Xml](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=Vietnam&adminDistrict=Hanoi&key=AgoUxsDIlzkI0CMxfAPSD1hSs6f82yEPWGIRcO6-HvLXLPAbMb2BE7O_FDq7mUmz&o=xml)

I want to read response text and return ObservableCollection

```
public void SearchLocation(string address)
{
var webclient = new WebClient();
        if (address != "")
        {
            string url =
                string.Format(
                    @"http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=Vietnam&adminDistrict=Ha Noi&locality={0}&o=xml&key={1}",
                    address, BingMapKey);
            webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
            webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += WebclientOnDownloadStringCompleted;
        }
    }

    private void WebclientOnDownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string data = e.Result;
        ReadXml(data);
    }

    private void ReadXml(string data)
    {
        _locations.Clear();


        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(data);
        var locations = from loca in document.Descendants("Location")
                            select
                                new Location(loca.Element("Name").Value,
                                            loca.Element("Point").Element("Latitude").Value,"1",
                                             "1", "1", "1", "1");

            _locations = (ObservableCollection<Location>) locations;

    }
}
```

Class Location:

```
public class Location
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Tên địa điểm
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Vĩ độ
    /// </summary>
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Kinh độ
    /// </summary>
    public double Longitute { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Vĩ độ Nam
    /// </summary>
    public double SouthLatitude { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Kinh độ Tây
    /// </summary>
    public double WestLongtitue { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Vĩ độ Bắc
    /// </summary>
    public double NorthLatitude { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Kinh độ Tây
    /// </summary>
    public double EastLongitude { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Khởi tạo Location
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">tên địa điểm</param>
    /// <param name="latitue">vĩ độ</param>
    /// <param name="longitude">kinh độ</param>
    /// <param name="southLatitude">vĩ độ nam</param>
    /// <param name="westLongitude">kinh độ tây</param>
    /// <param name="northLatitude">vĩ độ bắc</param>
    /// <param name="eastLongitude">kinh độ đông</param>
    public Location(string name, string latitue, string longitude, string southLatitude, string westLongitude,
                    string northLatitude, string eastLongitude)
    {
        Name = name;
        Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(latitue);
        Longitute = Convert.ToDouble(longitude);
        SouthLatitude = Convert.ToDouble(southLatitude);
        NorthLatitude = Convert.ToDouble(northLatitude);
        WestLongtitue = Convert.ToDouble(westLongitude);
        EastLongitude = Convert.ToDouble(eastLongitude);
    }
}
```

I read and _location return null, where are errors?

Comment: You'll have to post the actual code so we can help you out.

Comment: Is there any namespace declared in Location xml, if so then you need to query xml with namespace. [Resource link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/05/29/linq-to-xml-querying-xml-with-namespaces.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `IEnumerable<Location>` which is a result of LINQ to XML query to `ObservableCollection<Location>` directly.

```
_locations = (ObservableCollection<Location>) locations;
```

Just add all elements from query result collection into existing `ObservableCollection`:

```
foreach(var location in locations)
    _locations.Add(location);
```

***Update***

There is also namespace problem in your code. Try that one:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(data);

var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1");

var locations = from loca in document.Descendants(ns + "Location")
                select
                    new Location(loca.Element(ns + "Name").Value,
                                loca.Element(ns + "Point").Element(ns + "Latitude").Value, "1",
                                 "1", "1", "1", "1");
```

Comment: If `locations` returns no elements at all your LINQ to XML query is incorrect

Comment: Can you help me to find the mistake?

Comment: OK, but you have to post your input XML and `Location` class structure.

Comment: See my update - you were missing `XNamespace` within your query.